# Off-topic question reposted to the correct site; what to do with the carcass?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

It's common that new users <strike>sometimes</strike> often ask off-topic questions on Stack Overflow, like, uh, *this one*:

[image]
(*from [GemsFromStackExchange](http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/post/107992235305/when-programmers-become-exorcists)*)

...but however sometimes ones [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260911/openvpn-setup-on-debian-connection-made-but-no-internet) are asked that are off-topic for Stack Overflow but *are* on-topic for another Stack Exchange site:

[image]

When this *does* happen it's usually a good idea to point the user into the right direction by commenting that their question is better suited to a different website in the Stack Exchange network. The question is also normally closed as off-topic. The twist here is that sometimes the user forgets to remove (or aren't aware that they can delete their question) if they repost their question onto the [other Stack Exchange site](https://superuser.com/questions/872412/openvpn-setup-on-debian-connection-made-but-no-internet).

When this happens, the version of the question on Stack Overflow becomes a duplicate as the question was posted to a better site in the Network.

What is the appropriate action in this case?

Examples:

- Do nothing (since the question was closed as off-topic, we don't need to do anything else)
- Flag for deletion- the question is of no use to anybody on Stack Overflow (the question would probably of use to a *few* users here, but that's not the point) and the rotting carcass should be quietly buried/burnt.

Comment: There's no such thing as a cross-site duplicate.  In this context, migrations are better because a forwarding stub is left behind on the originating site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, but then migration requests often take a while unless they're posted on Meta or if I ask a moderator to do so (via chat or custom flag).